# Clearing up isNull() with "%" - Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, isnull

I am kinda confused what is being call with an `isNull`. Would anyone be able to explain better what is going on?

```
WHERE columnName LIKE isNull('something%','%')
```

Any information would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: that call's pointless. the string can never be null. `isnull(somefield + '%'` could be null, if the somefield value is null. but whate you've got could never succeed

Comment: @MarcB - It does seem to return sometihng, i just don't really understand it...

Comment: @MarcB is right, the entire point of ISNULL() is to evaluate if an expression/column is NULL... 'something' is a string literal, and thus cannot be NULL.  the % is the SQL equivalent of a wild card, and would also never be NULL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx what's not to understand? if the "check" value is null, then the second arg is returned, otherwise it returns the check value. since your string can never be null, it simply returns your string. in other words, it's functionally identical to `where columname like 'something%'`

Comment: It returns rows `WHERE columnName LIKE 'something%'`. The `ISNULL` call is pointless as the first parameter is a constant and not null.

Comment: @MartinSmith - okay that is what I thought. It was not my code and it just didnt really make sense to my why it was written like that. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcB - Thank you too for also clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT ISNULL(ColumnA,ColumnB)` will return `ColumnA` unless `Column A` is `null`, in which case it will return `ColumnB`.  If both values are `null`, it will return `NULL`.

Here's an example in [SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/265c6/1/0)